# Voice messages won't play through headphones (messenger)

Tags: audio, headphones, voice-message

I have the following problem: since yesterday in facebook messenger whenever someone sends me a voice message, I plug my headphones in and play it, but for some reason the sound comes from the speaker. Before it used to play through the headphones without problems.

I noticed that when I press the volume keys, it says the sound is identified as "sounds during conversation", which wasn't the case before. Before it came as "medias". This makes me believe the phone thinks I somehow told it to go through the loudspeaker as in normal phone conversations.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy J5 by the way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me as well. I Googled the issue and it turn out, that it may just be messenger's update. It started playing through my speakers after I updated, but my friend hasn't updated his and he can hear them through his headphones just fine. Your phone isn't to blame- it's just messenger's faulty update.

Answer (score 0):

[SoundAbout](https://soundabout.en.uptodown.com/android) (or [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix.pro&hl=en_US)) helps.

Note: As of now, given the reviews on the Play Store the Pro version merely buys the license but doesn't install the base app (which is no longer available in Play  Store), so buying it wouldn't be of any use.

Comment: I have added a note about the Pro app, so that folks don't end up buying it for no reason, and end up complaining you or us.

Comment: Oh… Good catch, thanks @Firelord